# Button like firebug or Greasemonkey in firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Is there anyone help me to create a menu type button like firebug or Greasemonkey using firefox addon sdk ?
Also if anyone know how to enable a disabled button in firefox addon sdk then please let me know.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/willlma/firefox-addon-sdk-menu-button) to do just what you're asking. It creates a menu-button type button and passes a second argument–boolean `isMenu`–to the button `onClick` method. Follow the link to see how to implement.